# frames not shown using view_frame node but in RViz

Tags: ros, frames, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am simulating mobile robot in Gazebo and visulizing in RViz. I have attached camera and laser links and corresponding Gazebo plugins and can successfully see them in RViz and Gazebo. I can see all the frames in TF tree in RVIz including laser link and camera link. However whenever I use `rosrun tf view_frames` to see the transform tree I noticed that laser and camera links are missing from there. The URDF clearly describes the parent and child links for laser and camera joints. Further to inform that `robot_sate_publisher` and `joint_sate_publisher` nodes are also running. Then my question is why can not I see laser joint and camera joint in `frames.pdf` generated using  `rosrun tf view_frames` but in RViz those joint transform are shown OK with correct transforms?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259341/frames-not-shown-using-view_frame-node-but-in-rviz/) by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2017-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you try `rosrun tf2_tools view_frames.py` http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_tools instead?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on 2017-04-15**:
Thank you. Now I can see all the links with their associated parent and child links. However I was wondering why `Average rate : 10000.0`, `Buffer length: 0.0`, `Most resent transform: 0.0`, `Oldest transform: 0.0` for camera and laser joints but non zero entries for the same for four wheel joints?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-04-16**:
Those are static transforms. They don't have a buffer length and are infinitely resolvable. The 10000.0 is just filled in to show a very high number. It can be considered infinity.

**Comment by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on 2017-04-16**:
Thank you for the reply.Your answer was really helpful.